# Rebasing barycentric coordinates to an adjacent triangle

Tags: geometry, barycentric-coordinates

Say that in a 2D space I have the barycentric coordinates **B**=(Bx, By, Bz) of point **P** relative to triangle **T**. I now need to calculate the barycentric coordinates **B'** of **P** relative to triangle **T'**, where **T** and **T'** share an edge - and thus, two of the three vertices.

Can I somehow simplify the calculation of these new barycentric coordinates given the fact that these two triangles share an edge?